# How do I put the icon in my electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron, icons

I want to put the icon on all of my App and not just on BrowserWindow, how do I do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'all of my App' ?

Comment: Icon of app, icon of executable, icon of windows, all of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Icon for electron Windows can be set in each `browserWindow`. Property `icon:`  needs to be set with icon path.
It's recomended to use `__dirname` and `path` module.

```
myWindow = new browserWindow({
  ...
  icon: path.join(__dirname, 'relative/path/to/myIcon.ico')
  ...
})
```

When packaging your application using `electron-packager` you need to set `--icon` flag pointing to an icon file; `.ico` for Windows, `.png` for linux and `.icns` for Mac.
This will set your **executable** icon.

Icon set when packaging, becomes default so every `browserWindow` with no `icon:`  property set will inherit it.

Comment: In the electron-packager, does this icon apply, for example, to application shortcuts, etc.?

Comment: Yes. Once the .exe gets an icon, OS will use it for application shortcuts. That's up to the OS, not electron.